Is it possible to have Plotly HTML charts appear within Colab without running the code beforehand?
I recently created a Python script that retrieves recent weather reports from the National Weather Service, then creates some simple Plotly visualizations of temperature and precipitation data. I configured a spare laptop to run this script on an hourly basis (using Papermill) and then copy the output to Google Drive, thus allowing relatively recent data to appear within this Colab notebook.
If I run and save this notebook on my local computer, then close and reopen it within JupyterLab Desktop or VS Code, the Plotly HTML-based charts will still appear (as long as Plotly is present within the active environment). In addition, if I run the notebook within Colab, the HTML charts will get produced there also.
However, I'm wondering whether it's possible for the interactive Plotly charts to appear within Colab without running the Colab notebook beforehand. This notebook does display static PNG copies of each chart by default, but until I actually run the notebook online, I only see blank spaces where the HTML charts should be:

(This screenshot from JupyterLab Desktop shows what I'd expect to see instead. Note that this HTML chart appeared by default when I opened the notebook; there was no need to run the script after opening JupyterLab in order to view this chart.)

In this case, it's not much trouble to just go ahead and run the notebook; however, other notebooks may make use of local files and folders and thus couldn't easily be run by others within Colab. Therefore, I'd love to find a method for showing interactive charts within Colab that doesn't require actually running the notebook.
Thank you in advance for your help!
PS: I know that an alternative setup would be to just display these interactive charts within a Dash app, but I may sometimes prefer to use a Jupyter Notebook as my medium in order to more easily display both my code and its output.

Are the notebooks at a URL that you know? If so you can use nbviewer to view them. It is the Jupyter Community-provided way to view notebooks that have been already pre-generated. Plotly plots usually maintain their interactivity when using nbviewer as it supports a lot of javascript-based features, like Plotly and FuncAnimation-related Animations saved as frames, even though the pre-run notebooks are often referred to as 'static'. See the bottom of my answer here for a link to an example. Or ...

 here or here. You'll see you can click on them and rotate or zoom in & out, etc..

I should have added that you can run it on your own network, too. See the nbviewer repo here.

@Wayne Thanks for your feedback! The HTML charts do appear correctly within this older copy of the notebook that I uploaded to GitHub. However, this notebook does not get updated automatically each hour, whereas the Colab version does.
Is there a way to automatically update my GitHub repository each hour with the latest Papermill-generated copy of the notebook? If so, that might be the best solution.

How to commit & push git updates on a scheduled basis is a different topic then this thread started with. You should look into github actions, too. Even if they get updated, the nbviewer doesn't clear out what it has very often. You'd probably need to run nbviewer yourself. Or use active MyBinder-served sessions to serve the most recent version. That clones the github repo each time. A fairly basic example is here. Go there and click the 'launch binder' badge to try it. Also see https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder .

Thanks for these additional recommendations. I've now set up an automated process for pushing a new copy of my notebook to GitHub. (In order to prevent my hourly commits from swelling the size of the repository, I decided to have my shell script delete and re-initialize my local Git repository whenever it produces a new copy of the notebook, then overwrite my existing GitHub repository with the new local one.) More details on the steps I took can be found at https://github.com/kburchfiel/pfn/blob/main/Automated_Notebooks/readme.md

I looked into Binder also, but I found that, like Colab, it would not display my Plotly HTML graphs by default. It does seem that, if you want to automatically update a set of Plotly charts that you're sharing with others, adding them to a Dash/Flask/Django app and connecting that app to a database might be the best option. For use cases that don't require HTML-based charts, though, the Colab solution appears to work fairly well.

I cannot speak to Colab as I don't regularly use it. However, I'm not following what you are saying about MyBinder. Whatever has been committed to GitHub will be run in the MyBinder session. And yes, it has to be run to update. You can though make an GitHub action that runs the notebook and commits the updated one. And you can use app dashboards with MyBinder and launch directly to the app/dashboard view. I have worked with Voila most.  It would probably make this easier if you specify why you say what you say?

My apologies for the confusion--what I meant was that, within Binder, the HTML Plotly charts in my notebook would not appear unless I reran the script. Until I did so, there would just be a blank space where the charts would normally appear. (In nbviewer, on the other hand, the HTML charts do show up automatically.)
I've actually found that NBViewer's copy of my GitHub page has been updating quite regularly during the last few days, so this might be the best solution. I also plan to look into GitHub project pages as another means of automatically updating and sharing notebooks with others.

"My apologies for the confusion--what I meant was that, within Binder, the HTML Plotly charts in my notebook would not appear unless I reran the script." Is the notebook set to be trusted?
